# How to write to a temporary file in Python and read from it again?

Tags: python, csv, temporary-files

I'm trying to write a unit test for a function that writes data to a CSV file. To this end, I'd like to use [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) to write to a named temporary file and open it again, which I understand from the documentation should be possible on Unix platforms.

However, if I try this test,

```
import csv
import tempfile


def write_csv(csvfile):
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=['foo', 'bar'])

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})


def test_write_csv():
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w') as csvfile:
        write_csv(csvfile)

    with open(csvfile.name) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
```

I get a `FileNotFoundError`:

```
> pytest csvtest.py -s
======================================= test session starts ========================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-5.0.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0
rootdir: /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Scratch
collected 1 item                                                                                   

csvtest.py F

============================================= FAILURES =============================================
__________________________________________ test_write_csv __________________________________________

    def test_write_csv():
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w') as csvfile:
            write_csv(csvfile)

>       with open(csvfile.name) as csvfile:
E       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/fr/7gjx_3js67xg0pjxz6sptktc0000gn/T/tmpgml8_fwf'

csvtest.py:16: FileNotFoundError
===================================== 1 failed in 0.03 seconds =====================================
```

I've tried various alternatives like trying to open the file in the same `with` block as it was written (in which case I get an error that it is not open for reading), opening in `'rw'` mode (in which case `csv` doesn't allow me to write to it).

How can I write a CSV to a temporary file and read it again in my unit test?

Comment: probably you have wrong indentions - you have to use `with open(csvfile.name) ...` inside `with temp.... as csvfile:` because `with tempfile.... as csvfile:` may delete this file when you leave `with`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to keep the temporary file after it is closed, you need to pass `delete=False`. From the documentation of [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) that you linked:

> If *delete* is true (the default), the file is deleted as soon as it is closed.

You would then just do:

```
import csv
import tempfile

def write_csv(csvfile):
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=['foo', 'bar'])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})

def test_write_csv():
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False) as csvfile:
        write_csv(csvfile)
    with open(csvfile.name) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
```

Comment: This is the best answer because I am actually able to read the data that was written, e.g. `reader.fieldnames` returns `['foo', 'bar']`. With the approaches described in the other two answers, the file is still empty from the `reader`'s perspective.

Answer (score 3):

The context of `csvfile` is gone once you leave the `with` and the temp file is deleted. Did you intend to do this?

```
def test_write_csv():
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w') as csvfile:
        write_csv(csvfile)

        with open(csvfile.name) as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
```

Probably not, since you reused `csvfile`. If you intend to keep the file you can pass `delete=false`

```
csvfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

When the execution of `with` block ends, the file is removed. So, maybe it's not the best solution but actually it works, so you can try it:

```py
def test_write_csv():
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w') as csvfile:
        write_csv(csvfile)
        with open(csvfile.name) as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
```